# How to check each value inside a list if not empty except one?

Tags: java, list, performance, automated-tests

So, we have a list of 10 values:

```
actualList = ['values','values','values','values','','values','values','values','values','values']
```

Need to check each value if not empty but 5 value must be empty. If it is true return some text else return some text.
I have a code like this:

```
if (actualList.get(0).isEmpty() && actualList.get(1).isEmpty() && actualList.get(2).isEmpty() && actualList.get(3).isEmpty() && actualList.get(4).isEmpty() &&
    !actualList.get(5).isEmpty() && actualList.get(6).isEmpty() && actualList.get(7).isEmpty() && actualList.get(8).isEmpty() && actualList.get(9).isEmpty()) {
return true;
} else return false;
```

but how to automate it?

Comment: Do you mean 5 value or 5. (fifth) value must be empty?

Comment: Your title is asking for opposite of what is posted in code example.

Comment: i mean 5 value must be empty

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
List<String> actualList = Arrays.asList("values","values","values","values", "values", "", "values","values","values","values");

return actualList.get(5).isEmpty() && 
       IntStream.range(0, actualList.size())
                .filter(i -> i != 5 && !actualList.get(i).isEmpty())
                .count() == 9;
```

Comment: I allowed myself to rewrite it a little since `print("false")` doesn't really make much sense if method is supposed to *return* result of validation. Also simplified `if(condition) return true; else return false;` to `return condition;`. Hope you don't mind.